# C++'s char * by swig got problem in Python 3.0

Tags: python-3.x, swig

Our C++ lib works fine with Python2.4 using Swig, returning a C++ char* back to a python str. But this solution hit problem in Python3.0, error is:

Exception=(, UnicodeDecodeError('utf8', b"\xb6\x9d\xa.....",0, 1, 'unexpected code byte')

Our definition is like(working fine in Python 2.4):

```
void  cGetPubModulus(
 void*  pSslRsa,
    char*  cMod,
    int*   nLen );

%include "cstring.i"
%cstring_output_withsize( char* cMod, int* nLen );
```

Suspect swig is doing a Bytes->Str conversion automatically. In python2.4 it can be implicit but in Python3.0 it's no long allowed.. Anyone got a good idea? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's rather Python 3 that does that conversion. In Python 2 bytes and str are the same thing, in Python 3 str is unicode, so something somewhere tries to convert it to Unicode with UTF8, but it's not UTF8.

Your Python 3 code needs to return not a Python str, but a Python bytes. This will not work with Python 2, though, so you need preprocessor statements to handle the differences.

Answer (score 3):

I came across a similar problem. I wrote a SWIG typemap for a custom `char` array (an `unsigned char` in fact) and it got SEGFAULT when using Python 3. So I debugged the code within the typemap and I realized the problem Lennart states.

My solution to that problem was doing the following in that typemap:

```c
%typemap(in) byte_t[MAX_FONTFACE_LEN] {
   if (PyString_Check($input))
   {
     $1 = (byte_t *)PyString_AsString($input);
   }
   else if  (PyUnicode_Check($input))
   {
     $1 = (byte_t *)PyUnicode_AsEncodedString($input, "utf-8", "Error ~");
     $1 = (byte_t *)PyBytes_AS_STRING($1);
   }
   else
   {
     PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"Expected a string.");
     return NULL;
   }
}
```

That is, I check what kind of string object `PyObject` is. The functions `PyString_AsString()` and `PyUnicode_AsString()` will return `> 0` if its input it's an UTF- 8 string or an Unicode string respectively. If it's an Unicode string, we convert that string to bytes in the call `PyUnicode_AsEncodedString()` and later on we convert those bytes to a `char *` with the call `PyBytes_AS_STRING()`.

Note that I vaguely use the same variable for storing the unicode string and converting it later to bytes. Despite of being that questionable and maybe, it could derive in another coding-style discussion, the fact is that I solved my problem. I have tested it out with `python3` and `python2.7` binaries without any problems yet.

And lastly, the last line is for replicating an exception in the python call, to inform about that input wasn't a string, either utf nor unicode.